# Can anyone explain the meaning of this statement?

Tags: meaning

The land described herein shall not be deemed to include any house trailer or mobile home standing on said
premises.

Comment: Look up the definitions of "house trailer" and "mobile home".

Comment: When the land is sold, there may be a house trailer or mobile home on it.  If so, that trailer/home is not part of the transaction.  (Presumably it will be moved, or the owner of it will begin paying lot rent to the new landowner.)

Answer (score 2):

The land -> a piece of land
described herein -> described in this document
shall not be deemed to include -> shall not be seen as 
land + something else"

That "something else" is "any house, trailer or mobile home"

standing on said premises. -> that is standing on that piece of land.

In a simple way:

> When we talk about "the land" in this document, we mean just the land, not any house, trailer or mobile home that is on that land.

or very short:

> We are talking about the land without any of the mentioned things on it.

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as "without anything" after it has excluded mobile homes and trailers. If I was buying such deeds, and the land had a fixed structure on it, I'd want clarification beyond that sentence as to whether the fixed structure came with the land or not.

Comment: @JonHanna You're right, there are other things that may be on the land and included in the deal.

Answer (score 0):

It means the land being described shouldn't be considered or assumed to contain a house trailer or a mobile home within its boundaries.

Comment: Even if it does.